# Long Post - How can I make my Asset Action Utility script to automatically save multiple assets as blueprint?

Tags: unreal-engine5

I made the script takes multiple assets, and converts them into a blueprint. The problem is that I have to select the folder destination for every single asset. How can I make it so that I can just select the folder directory and blueprint prefix once, and it automatically names them by number?

**Header file**

```
    UFUNCTION(CallInEditor)
    void CreateBPInteractiveObjectPieceFromAsset();
```

**CPP File**

```
void UAAU_CreateDestructibleObject::CreateBPInteractiveObjectPieceFromAsset()
{
    //Get selected assets and put into an array of asset type
    TArray<UObject*> Assets = UEditorUtilityLibrary::GetSelectedAssets();

    //iterate through asset array
    for (int i = 0; i < Assets.Num(); ++i){
        //cast i-th UObject asset to UStaticMesh 
        UStaticMesh* StaticMeshAsset = Cast<UStaticMesh>(Assets[i]);
        
        //Create Blueprint
        //Create package
        //Doesn't work for some reason
        UPackage* Package = CreatePackage(TEXT("/Game/Blueprints/ADestructibleObject"));

        //Create Blueprint from selected (static mesh) asset; this one opens a dialogue box for every asset (to set the directory path) 
        UBlueprint* CreatedBlueprint = FKismetEditorUtilities::CreateBlueprintUsingAsset(Assets[i], false);
        //reparent the created blueprint to a LiftableObjectPiece 
        CreatedBlueprint->ParentClass = ADestructibleObject::StaticClass();

        //if createdBlueprint is not a nullptr/successfully created a blueprint
        if (CreatedBlueprint)
        {
            // Notify the asset registry
            FAssetRegistryModule::AssetCreated(CreatedBlueprint);

            // Mark the package dirty...
            Package->MarkPackageDirty();
        }
    }
}
```